What should I do if I get this error Fatal error, could not stop test, exiting errorlevel=1?
I executed a test using non gui mode. The test is supposed to ran for 5 mins only but it's running for more than 5 mins.
I clicked stoptest.cmd then I got this message in cmd
Starting standalone test @ 2024 Aug 15 21:16:50 CST (1723727810648)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
Command: StopTestNow received from /127.0.0.1
Fatal error, could not stop test, exiting
errorlevel=1
Press any key to continue . . .
It says could not stop test. What should I do to stop the test?
Appreciate help. Thanks

First, kill it if there is anything hanging:
pkill -f jmeter 

Then, increase stop timeout: in jmeter.properties, set jmeterengine.force.system.exit=true to forcefully terminate the test, that makes sure JMeter shuts down completely, even if some threads or processes are hanging, preventing indefinite test runs.
Clean your code and make sure there are no infinite loops or blocking threads causing the issue.
Use a static code analyzing tools like SonarQube or PMD to detect potential infinite loops, blocking code, and a whole range of stuff that can cause nightmares later on, you want to find junk in the early stages of coding, it really pays off.
Good luck!

This message/error is printed when JMeter cannot stop all threads (virtual users)
The reasons could be in:

JMeter is overloaded (incorrect configuration, lack of resources, etc.). Make sure to follow 9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure article to properly configure JMeter for high loads

The system under test is overloaded and doesn't respond. JMeter by default will wait for the response forever, if this is the case - it would be a good idea to set reasonable connect/response timeouts. For the HTTP Request sampler the setting lives under "Advanced" tab



